# How to debug INPC property setter not triggered?

Tags: c#, properties, windows-phone-8.1, inotifypropertychanged

**Overview:**
I've set up a property with INPC that invokes a page navigation in the view code behind from the `MainViewModel`. This property is bound to the *SelectedItem* property of a list view in the bound view.

The INPC implementation is inherited from the `ViewModelBase` class which is implemented as follows, https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/4a0890b678e037296aba

**Issue:**

When I select an item from the list view, the property `SelectedCouncilItem` setter doesn't trigger. This property is bound to the *SelectedItem* property of the list view.

**Debugging Steps:**

- Checked binding names for SelectedItem in list view property, which was the same as the property name in the MainViewModel.
- Ran the solution and checked for any binding errors in the output window, which there were none.
- Placed a break point on the SelectedCouncilItem which doesn't get triggered when I select from the list view.
- Checked the data context setup for the view which verified that the view is set to the data context of the MainViewModel.

**Question:**

Does anyone know what other steps I can take in debugging the issue, or what the issue might be?

**Code:**

MainPage - (List View)

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector"
                                Margin="0,0,-12,0"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCouncilItem}">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                                   Text="{Binding CouncilAcronym}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,-6,12,0"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"
                                   Text="{Binding CouncilFullName}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

MainViewModel - (summary)

```
namespace ParkingTagPicker.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {


        //Dependency Injection private instances
        private INavigationCallback _navCallBack = null;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items  collection.
        /// </summary>
        public void LoadCouncilNamesData()
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "6", CouncilAcronym = "WTC", CouncilFullName = "Wicklow Town Council"});
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "7", CouncilAcronym = "TS", CouncilFullName = "Tallaght Stadium" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "8", CouncilAcronym = "GS", CouncilFullName = "Greystones" });

            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }



        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

        public bool IsDataLoaded { get; private set; }

        private ItemViewModel _selectedCouncilItem;
        public ItemViewModel SelectedCouncilItem
        {          
            get
            {
                return this._selectedCouncilItem;
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this._selectedCouncilItem, value, () => this._selectedCouncilItem);

                if (_selectedCouncilItem != null)
                {
                    _navCallBack.NavigateTo(_selectedCouncilItem.ID);
                }
            }
        }


        public INavigationCallback NavigationCallback
        {
            get { return _navCallBack; }
            set { _navCallBack = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

ViewModelBase - (detailing INPC implementation)

```
namespace ParkingTagPicker.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;

            if (propertyChanged != null)
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingField, T Value, Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
        {
            var changed = !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, Value);

            if (changed)
            {
                backingField = Value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpression));
            }

            return changed;
        }

        private static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
        {
            var memberExp = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

            if (memberExp == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a MemberExpression.", "propertyExpression");
            }

            return memberExp.Member.Name;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with the control. Please try using custom LongListSeletor

```
public class ExtendedLongListSelector : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector
{
    public ExtendedLongListSelector()
    {
        SelectionChanged += LongListSelector_SelectionChanged;
    }

    void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(LongListSelector),
                            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = (LongListSelector)d;
        selector.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }   


    public new object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and implement in replace it in XAML with the existing List.

```
   xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ProjectName.FolderName"

   <controls:ExtendedLongListSelector  x:Name="MainLongListSelector"
                                Margin="0,0,-12,0"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCouncilItem}">
   </controls:ExtendedLongListSelector>
```

Comment: I tried first adding the above class, http://hastebin.com/ahudowakop.cs  there was a mistake in the ctor name so changed that. The only error I get in the class is on SetSelectedItem stating it's not in LongListSelector. Any ideas what's up? Also how does implementing this extended list selector solve the issue in the question?

Comment: use  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCouncilItem}". No need to call SetSelectedItem

Comment: so I need to remove this method from the class above?  private void SetSelectedItem(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }

Comment: No. never remove anything from it. Build your code & paste me the exact debug error

Comment: Edited  answer . Please change it & let me know .